# Component-specific Castle Windsor typed factory

Tags: c#, database-connection, castle-windsor, typed-factory-facility

I have an application that uses several different database connections.  I would like to use Castle Windsor's typed factory support to inject a factory that returns instances of `IDbConnection` into my repositories and other components.

Here's how the interface for my typed factory looks like:

```
public interface IConnectionFactory
{
    IDbConnection CreateConnection();
}
```

And here's a sample repository:

```
public class AccountRepository
{
     private readonly IConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

     public AccountRepository(IConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
     {
         this.connectionFactory = connectionFactory;
     }

     public Account FindAccountById(int id)
     {
         using (var connection = connectionFactory.CreateConnection())
         {
             // TODO use the connection here
         }
     }
}
```

And an excerpt of my component registration:

```
// ...

container.Register(Component.For<IDbConnection>()
    .ImplementedBy<NpgsqlConnection>()
    .LifestyleTransient());

container.Register(Component.For<IConnectionFactory>()
     .AsFactory());

// ...
```

All my `IDbConnection`s are implemented using the same type (`NpgsqlConnection`), but I have several different connection strings I need to use.  Ideally, I would like to setup Windsor to set the connection string on the `IDbConnection` (or pass it into the connection constructor) for me depending on the component that has `IConnectionFactory` as a dependency.

For example:

- Say I have two repositories, `AccountRepository` and `ItemRepository`, that take `IConnectionFactory` as a dependency in their constructors.
- Say I also have two connection strings named `foo` and `bar`.
- When `AccountRepository` calls `IConnectionFactory.CreateConnection()`, I want it to return an `IDbConnection` using connection string `foo`.
- However, when a `ItemRepository` calls `IConnectionFactory.CreateConnection()`, I want it to return an `IDbConnection` using connection string `bar`.

*Is this possible with Castle Windsor?*

I've researched this topic but haven't find any solution that fits my exact scenario.  Ideally, I would like to keep my repositories ignorant of the exact connection string to use, i.e. I do ***not*** want to change my connection factory to:

```
public interface IConnectionFactory
{
    IDbConnection CreateConnection(string connectionStringName);
}
```

I've also read all the documentation and articles I could find on `ISubDependencyResolver` and `ITypedFactoryComponentSelector` but I'm not sure if they are applicable in this scenario or how to piece everything together.

By the way, I am using Castle Windsor 3.1 and .NET 4.0.

Comment: Would named components give you what you want? I think this would allow you to express the specific dependencies at registration time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe use a real Factory, and not a typed one:

```
public ConnectionAFactory : IConnectionFactory
{
     public ConnectionAFactory()
     {
          this.connectionString = "foo";
     }
}
```

And register it in windsor with the correct Repository:

```
Component.For<AccountRepository>()
    .DependsOn(
        ServiceOverride.ForKey<IConnectionFactory>().Eq(typeof(ConnectionAFactory)));
```